# Interrupt while placing process on the waiting queue

Tags: semaphore, interrupt, critical-section

> Suppose there is a process that is trying to enter the critical region but since it is occupied by some other process, the current process has to wait for it. So, at the time when the process is getting added to the waiting queue of the semaphore, suppose an interrupt comes (ex- battery finished), then what will happen to that process and the waiting queue?

I think that since the battery has finished so this interrupt will have the highest priority and so the context of the process which was placing the process on the waiting queue would be saved and interrupt service routine for this routing will be executed.

And then it will return to the process that was placing the process on the queue.

Please give some hints/suggestions for this question.

Comment: The answer to this question greatly depends on the design of the OS. Your OS can just cease all execution at that moment or the battery can run out before the OS does all the data saving. Too little information.

Answer (score 1):

This is very hardware / OS dependant, however a few thoughts:

As has been mentioned in the comments, a ‘battery finished’ interrupt may be considered as a special case, simply because the machine may turn off without taking any action, in which case the processes + queue will disappear.  In general however, assuming a non-fatal interrupt and an OS that suspends / resumes correctly, I think it’s unlikely there will be any noticeable impact to the execution of either process.

In a multi-core setup, the process may not be immediately suspended.  The interrupt could be handled by a different core and neither of the processes you’ve mentioned would be any the wiser.

In a pre-emptive multitasking OS there's also no guarantee that the process adding to the queue would be resumed immediately after the interrupt, the scheduler could decide to activate the process currently in the critical section or another process entirely.  What would happen when the process adding itself to the semaphore wait queue resumed would depend on how far through adding it was, how the queue has been implemented and what state the semaphore was in.  It may be that it never gets on to the wait queue because it detects that the other process has already woken up and left the critical section, or it may be that it completes adding itself to the queue and suspends as if nothing had happened…

In a single core/processor machine with a cooperative multitasking OS, I think the scenario you’ve described in your question is quite likely, with the executing process being suspended to handle the interrupt and then resumed afterwards until it finished adding itself to the queue and yielded.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the implementation, but conceptually the same operating process should be performing both the addition of the process to the wait queue and the management of the interrupts, so your process being moved to wait would instead be treated as interrupted from the wait queue.

For Java, see the API for [`Thread.interrupt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29)

> Interrupts this thread.
>
> Unless the current thread is interrupting itself, which is always permitted, the checkAccess method of this thread is invoked, which may cause a SecurityException to be thrown.
>
> **If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the wait()**, wait(long), or wait(long, int) methods of the Object class, or of the join(), join(long), join(long, int), sleep(long), or sleep(long, int), methods of this class, then **its interrupt status will be cleared and it will receive an InterruptedException**.
>
> If this thread is blocked in an I/O operation upon an interruptible channel then the channel will be closed, the thread's interrupt status will be set, and the thread will receive a ClosedByInterruptException.
>
> If this thread is blocked in a Selector then the thread's interrupt status will be set and it will return immediately from the selection operation, possibly with a non-zero value, just as if the selector's wakeup method were invoked.
>
> If none of the previous conditions hold then this thread's interrupt status will be set.
>
> Interrupting a thread that is not alive need not have any effect.